# How to resolve differences in methods in the .lib file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, linker-errors

I am trying to get a 3rd party library to work with my code. I have the source to the library, and have verified that the build options match my own build options, but I have not gone though all the source code to learn what it is doing.

My code calls the line `Value m_jsonValRoot;` which gives me the following linking errors:

```
Linking...
1>JsonWrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Json::Value::~Value(void)" (??1Value@Json@@QAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsOS<wchar_t> > > __cdecl Json::CJsonWrapper::RunTest(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsOS<wchar_t> > >)" (?RunTest@CJsonWrapper@Json@@QAA?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsOS@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V34@@Z)
1>JsonWrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Json::Value::Value(int)" (??0Value@Json@@QAA@H@Z) referenced in function "public: class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsOS<wchar_t> > > __cdecl Json::CJsonWrapper::RunTest(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsOS<wchar_t> > >)" (?RunTest@CJsonWrapper@Json@@QAA?AV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsOS@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V34@@Z)
1>Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Standard DTK (ARMV4I)\Debug\CCRDEX_UI.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I ran dumpbin on the .lib file, and i found my function was defined as:

```
SECTION HEADER #C7
   .text name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
     194 size of raw data
   22345 file pointer to raw data (00022345 to 000224D8)
   224D9 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
      12 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60501020 flags
         Code
         COMDAT; sym= "public: __thiscall Json::Value::Value(enum Json::ValueType)" (??0Value@Json@@QAE@W4ValueType@1@@Z)
         16 byte align
         Execute Read
```

I attempted to resolve this by changing the method declaration in the headder file from: `Value( ValueType type = nullValue );` to `__thiscall Value( ValueType type = nullValue );`, however this had no impact on the linker.

I am building a project in Visual Studio 2008 using MFC in a shared DLL, using unicode, and am building for Windows Mobile 6.5.3

What steps can I take to reslove the linking issues?

Comment: Don't edit the header, that just digs you a deeper hole.  Focus on the missing destructor instead.  You have provided no evidence that you are actually *linking* this library.  Which is the simple explanation.

Comment: it was just a test to hopefully resolve it... i undid it when it had no impact.

I placed the header files in the project directly, I also included the path in 'additional include directories'

the .lib file is included under 'Additional Dependencies'

Comment: I have confirmed that the .lib is (was) correctly linked. I tampered with it and got a different error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'json_debug_vc90_libmtd.lib''... so I know that it was origionally linking to the lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something forgetful when building the lib files.

I accidently was building it for Win32 when I needed to be building it for a mobile device.